# crawling intranet credentials issues

Tags: search, web-crawler, open-search-server

I've been trying to crawl and index the intranet and the internet. But It doesn't work at all, I think it's due to proxy/security restrictions. I get the indexed parsed to true but the content length is -1 so it crawls nothing. Is there anyway I can put the credentiels I have on the intranet to crawl it in open search server knowing that it has only basic/Digest or NTLM authentication?

Is there anyway to configure the proxy on oss more than just on the one in the crawler tab?
I have set the credentials but it doesn't seem like oss recognises the proxy of the company so it doesn't give me the box to enter the credentials.

Comment: There are a lot of issues with this question that will keep people from wanting to tackle it. For starters, 1) You're trying to index the entire Internet? You're going to need massive, multi-billion-dollar datacenters to pull that off. 2) "it doesn't work at all" - what is "it"? Without going into detail about what you're trying to do and what tools you're using, everything after your first sentence is meaningless. I recommend describing the specific tools and steps you are using, and describing the exact input/output. People here will be eager to help when they understand the problem.

Comment: I have stated the tool open search server Mr Fig ;) and I'm not trying to crawl all the internet. concerning the problem, It was a proxy problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.5.4, OpenSearchServer supports authentication on proxy.

Here is the GITHub issue:
https://github.com/jaeksoft/opensearchserver/issues/589

For now, the v1.5.4 is only available as nightly build.

[image]